# Find the asymptotic time complexity of the following

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

while(n>1){
   n = sqrt(n);
}

Where sqrt returns the root of n. n = 2^k and k is a power of 2.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: My thought process was - let's say at iteration 't' n value becomes equal to 1. So, lets say k = 2^a, then (2^(2^(a-t))) = 1 which gives 2^(a-t) = 0, which is impossible. This is where I got stuck.